# Apache: combine two AliasMatch statements into one

Tags: web-server, apache-2.4, httpd.conf, regex

Could be the following `AliasMatch` statements for Apache 2.4 combined into one?

```
AliasMatch ^/([0-9]{6})$ /var/www/data/$1
AliasMatch ^/([0-9]{6})/(.*)$ /var/www/data/$1/$2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BillThor only forgot to add the *s in the patterns. Either:

AliasMatch ^/([0-9]{6}(/.*)?)$ /var/www/data/$1

or

AliasMatch ^/([0-9]{6})((/.*)?)$ /var/www/data/$1$2

The first for preference.

Comment: And this one works and gave me helpful insight how regex expressions can be combined. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You have full regular expressions for the match so either of these should work.

```
AliasMatch ^/([0-9]{6}(/.*)?)$ /var/www/data/$1
AliasMatch ^/([0-9]{6})((/.*)?)$ /var/www/data/$1$2
```

Comment: No. They don't.